# How to start Orchard Advanced Menu?

Tags: drop-down-menu, content-management-system, orchardcms

Sorry for a silly question, but I really had no clue on how to add a plug-in menu in orchard.

Had just downloaded orchard CMS for testing, and downloaded a widget called advance menu,
However I had no idea how it works, it does not work like adding a page.

Is there any tutorials on this add-on?

Comment: That module is not compatible with the current version of Orchard, as far as I know.

Comment: huh? that means crap from me. Being like a day on the stupid modules already..

Comment: What is the feature from advanced menu that you need and that the built-in menu doesn't give you?

Comment: some pull down menu, tree menu

Comment: Not sure what you mean by tree menu, but the built-in navigation supports nested items. How you display it is just a matter of using a theme that supports it or overriding a few templates and styles.

Answer (score 0):

This is from pszmyd, the author of the Orchard Advanced Menu:

pszmyd Mod  Michelle Foster • 3 years ago

1. You need to create a menu - 'main' menu is there by default.
2. You need to enter the management screen of the chosen menu (from the admin menu on the right) and add the menu items you need
3. Create a widget that will display the menu you created in previous steps. There are two widgets to choose from - Menu Widget (which renders just plain HTML without any styling) or Styled Menu Widget (which adds some preconfigured styling and scripts).

Link: http://www.szmyd.com.pl/blog/orchard-advanced-menu-1.3-released (Look down in the comments)

There is not currently a more extensive tutorial available, but if you're familiar with Orchard you should be able to figure it out.